# Show Simple DataTable as a calendar, in stimulsoft

Tags: calendar, report, stimulsoft

I have a data-table as a Data-source with just two columns:

1. Date
2. Value (the value of Value Column always is 1 for every Row)

Now, I need to show this DataTable like a Calendar, with a sum column.
I tried to do this, using "Cross-Tab", "Cross-Data" , and many other ways, but no way i founded.

[image: Please check my attached picture]

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add 12 Data Bands with filters for each month.
Then put Cross-Data with Count = 31.
Finally, you should put Data Band on the Cross-Data with filters for each day.